# IVP and the homogeniety of DE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If $$y'' + y = \begin{cases}2, & t \le 3 \\[2ex] 
             3t-7,& 3 < t < \infty
\end{cases}$$
$y(0) = 0, y'(0) = 0$

then, how can we apply the laplace transformation?

Comment: These seem to be homework problems!

Comment: It is not, just some additional book problems for self-study since I never learned Laplace

Comment: OK!  Then try to work the understand how to solve the previous one in order to tackle this one!

Comment: I would, if you could help me out with the other one!

Answer (score 0):

Derivate both sides. You get:

$$y'''+y'= 3 H(t-3)$$

where $H$ is the Heaviside "step function" (equal to $1$ for $t>0$, to $0$ when $t \leq 0$). The first coefficient $3$ because of the slope of $3t-7$, the second $3$ because on $[0,3]$ the slope is $0$ (in short :  slope =  derivative).

I leave you the rest of the calculation, which will depend a priori on 3 constant of integration, but you will manage to compute one of them by "checking" your result with the initial second order differential equation.

As the homogeneous (initial) associated equation is $y''+y=0$ (harmonic oscillator), you should end up with solutions involving circular functions.